# prove that there exists a perfect cube that divides 135 consecutive integers

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences, chinese-remainder-theorem

how would you prove that for 135 consecutive integers $a_1,a_2,...,a_{135}$ such that for all integers $k$, $1 \leq k \geq 135$ there exists a perfect cube $z_k > 1$ such that $z_k$ divides $a_k$?

Im stuck on this question and don't even know how to start. All I know is that if $z_k$ divides $a_k$ then $a_k = mod (z_k)$

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding the question you are asking. Do you want to show that there exists $135$ consecutive integers such that each of these integers is divisible by a perfect cube?

Comment: @AnuragA the title is wrong, the question body is alright

Answer (score 2):

If the question is what I have stated in my comment then, consider $135$ distinct primes $p_1,p_2, \ldots, p_{135}$. Now consider the following system of congruences:
\begin{align*}
x & \equiv 0 \pmod{p_1^3}\\
x & \equiv -1 \pmod{p_2^3}\\
x & \equiv -2 \pmod{p_3^3}\\
\vdots & \equiv \vdots\\
x & \equiv -134 \pmod{p_{135}^3}
\end{align*}
Then by the Chinese remainder theorem, there exists a solution $x_0$ to this system. Thus $\{x_0,x_0+1,x_0+2, \ldots, x_0+134\}$ will satisfy the given requirements.

Comment: arent you assuming the conclusion by making all those congruences?

Comment: @Skrrrrrtttt no I am not assuming the conclusion. By setting up those congruences there is no guarantee of a solution. At that stage we are merely asking can this system have a solution?  It is CRT that helps us answer that.